# How to write *.mp4 video with OpenCV-C++?

Tags: c++, opencv, mp4, codec, imx6

I'm using OpenCV-C++ to write  video *.mp4 type. I can write video .avi type but It's take a lot of storage. About 1Mb/1s with 640x480 resolution and 15 FPS. I'm using iMX6UL-EVK board(Linux).

**I built without error but no output .mp4 file. And in python code (OpenCV-Python), this board can write .mp4 video with "mp4v".**

I tried with "mp4v", "xvid", "divx", "h264", "x264" but not working. So what can I do now? Or may you show me others type of video which not take much of storage ?

This is my code:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Built with OpenCV " << CV_VERSION << endl;
    Mat image;
    Mat src;
    VideoCapture capture;
    capture.open(2);
    capture >> src;
    bool isColor = (src.type() == CV_8UC3);
    VideoWriter writer;
    int codec = VideoWriter::fourcc('M', 'P', '4', 'V');  
    double fps = 15.0;
    string filename = "live.mp4";
    Size sizeFrame(640,480);
    writer.open(filename, codec, fps, sizeFrame, isColor);
    cout << "Started writing video... " << endl;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 60 ; i ++)
    {
        capture >> image;
        Mat xframe;
        resize(image,xframe,sizeFrame);
        writer.write(xframe);
        // imshow("Sample", image);
        // char c = (char)waitKey(1);
        // if(c == 27) break;
    }
    cout << "Write complete !" << endl;
    capture.release();
    writer.release();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine in my pc? Your operating systems support *.mp4*?

Comment: You should be checking the return values from `writer.open(...` etc.

Comment: Have you checked what codecs are installed on your system?

Comment: In python code (OpenCV-Python), this board can write .mp4 video with "mp4v".

Comment: Actually, my board has no codec hardware, only codec software available.

Comment: My board can play both .avi and .mp4 video with gst-play-1.0 command

Comment: How to check what codecs are installed on my system ? May you tell me, pls ?

Answer (score 3):

```
VideoWriter::fourcc('a', 'v', 'c', '1')
```

work fine for me to write mp4 file.